# Replacement for CoRD (Microsoft RDP )

Tags: software-recommendation, remote-desktop

I've been using [CoRD](http://cord.sourceforge.com) heavily over the last few years, in my day-to-day job where I need to connect to Microsoft RDP servers. CoRD is perfect for my needs, mainly as it presents a single "unified" view: rather than having lots of windows open, there's just one window for all connected servers, and I click between which one I want to view.

However, CoRD was a bit flaky on Yosemite, and is downright unstable on El Capitan. I've tried various other RDP packages, including the "official" Microsoft client, but none of them are as simple and/or useful as CoRD.

CoRD development seems to have been abandoned years ago. Does anyone know of an alternative RDP client that'll easily support multiple simultaneous connections, preferably in a single window?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I've found, and am now loving, [Royal TSX](http://www.royalapplications.com/ts/osx/features). Not only does it do exactly what I loved CoRD for - multiple RDP connections in a single window - it has a plugin system that'll connect to VNC, TeamViewer, web pages etc, and more in the future. The RDP plugin is based on [FreeRDP](http://www.freerdp.com/), and seems to support the latest RDP protocol enhancements.

Some of the functionality requires the companion server product, and it'll only do 10 connections in "free" mode ($29 for unlimited connections). But given that it's a stable, feature-rich client that is being actively developed, I can recommend it highly.

Comment: Best feature: native DPI scaling.

Comment: Update for 2021: This continues to be a great alternative. It remembers window positions and sizes, offers shift-control-click to emulate right-click. It is still in active development. Shareware (free) version still offers 10 connections, but he's raised the price for commercial users ($50)

Answer (score 2):

I have moved to [VM Fusion](http://www.vmware.com/products/fusion/) and created a Windows 8.1 virtual machine and on that run the Windows Remote Desktop Connection Manager. Not a free solution but an incredible improvement over just using Cord. Now that Cord is basically unusable I am so relived I'd moved before upgrading to El Capitan.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same issues with Cord on El Capitan, I've been using the 14 day trial of Jump Desktop and it seems very nice and stable thus far.

Answer (score 1):

Jump Desktop is great and can sync nicely between your Mac and iDevices. Only problem is on the Mac it opens each desktop in a new window. As others have said, I much prefer the unified window. Anxious to try Royal TSX.